# divergence theorem and power

Tags: divergence-operator, weak-derivatives

given the equation

$$ 0 = \int_\Omega \Delta  (p ^m) v dx $$

with $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and assuming zero boundary conditions.

Is it possible to write something like

$$ 0 = \int_\Omega \nabla  (p ^m) \nabla v dx $$

using the divergence theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true if you assume that either $v$ or $\nabla p^m$ vanish on the boundary. You have
$$
\nabla\cdot(v\nabla p^m)=v\Delta p^m+\nabla v\cdot\nabla p^m 
$$
Integrating over $\Omega$, the left hand side can be transformed using Stokes' Thm
$$
\int\limits_{\Omega}\nabla\cdot(v\nabla p^m)dx=\int\limits_{\partial\Omega}v\nabla p^m\cdot dS
$$
which vanishes if either $v$ or $\nabla p^m$ vanish on the boundary.Therefore, you are left with
$$
\int\limits_{\Omega}v\Delta p^m\,dx=-\int\limits_{\Omega}\nabla v\cdot\nabla p^m\,dx 
$$
and if one of them vanishes, the other one vanishes as well.